# Не получается найти индекс второго совпадения в последовательности

Tags: python, python-3.x, итераторы

Необходимо реализовать функцию find_second_index, осуществляющую поиск индекса второго совпадения в последовательности при помощи функции find_index и итераторов:

```
def find_index(value, items):
    for index, item in enumerate(items):
        if item == value:
            return index


def find_second_index(value, items):
    it = iter(items)
    find_index(value, it)
    return find_index(value, it)
```

При следующей проверке функция работает правильно:

```
find_second_index('!', '!') is None
True
```

Но потом функция выдает индекс первого совпадения, а не второго:

```
find_second_index(2, [1, 2, 3, 2])
1
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, итерация для `enumerate` начинается заново, т.е. с 0 индекса.

Хоть, в первый раз итератор успел в `enumerate` вернуть 2 элемента, и `find_index` вернуло индекс 1.

Во второй раз итератор вернул еще два элемента, т.е. снова вернулся индекс 1.

Можно попробовать складывать индекс с первой попытки ко второй.

Пример:

```
def find_index(value, items):
    for index, item in enumerate(items):
        if item == value:
            return index

    return -1

def find_second_index(value, items):
    it = iter(items)
    i = find_index(value, it)
    if i == -1:
        return -1

    i2 = find_index(value, it)
    if i2 == -1:
        return -1
    return i2 + i + 1
```

Либо, изначально хранить итератор от `enumerator`:

```
def find_index(value, it):
    for index, item in it:
        if item == value:
            return index

    return -1

def find_second_index(value, items):
    it = enumerate(items)
    find_index(value, it)
    return find_index(value, it)
```

Тестирование:

```
print(find_second_index(2, [1, 2, 3, 2]))
# 3

print(find_second_index(2, [1, 2, 2, 3]))
# 2

print(find_second_index(2, [2, 2, 2, 3]))
# 1

print(find_second_index(2, [1, 3, 4]))
# -1

print(find_second_index(2, [1, 3, 4, 2, 2]))
# 4

print(find_second_index(2, [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]))
# -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал проще: генерируем список индексов элементов, совпадающих с нужным нам, и возвращаем второй по счету. Не забываем проверку на единственность искомого элемента.

```
def find_2nd(to_find, x):
    return [i for i, n in enumerate(x) if n == to_find][1] if x.count(to_find) > 1 else None


print(find_2nd(2, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 444, 2])) # 6
print(find_2nd(77, [1, 2, 3, 5, 77, 6, 444, 2]))  # None
```

Comment: Всё-таки в вопросе явно указано, что нужно использовать итераторы

Comment: @Xander упс) Ну я на правильность ответа не претендую, такой есть ниже. Просто оставлю как еще один вариант реализации

Comment: Нужно было использовать итераторы, но все равно спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать `find_index` как генератор (`return` заменить на `yield`), тогда каждый следующий индекс можно будет запрашивать через `next`:

```
def find_index(value, items):
    for index, item in enumerate(items):
        if item == value:
            yield index

print(next(find_index(2, [1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2])))  # 3

print(list(find_index(2, [1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2])))  # [3, 6]
```

Тогда в `find_second_index` можно первый результат пропустить, а второй вернуть:

```
def find_second_index(value, items):
    result = find_index(value, items)
    try:
        next(result)  # первый результат пропускаем
        return next(result)  # второй возвращаем
    except StopIteration:  # обрабатываем случай, если совпадений нет или только одно
        return None

print(find_second_index(2, [1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2]))  # 6

print(find_second_index(2, [2]))  # None
```